# About signal conversion

Tags: circuit-design, electrical, electricity, power-engineering

Question is weird but it's about something that I really want to try.

AC power here in India has 50Hz frequency. What I really want to try is to make a series path with two continuous conversions. In start, I want to convert 50Hz AC 230V signal to 100Hz 230V AC signal and at the end of this path I want it to became the same signal of 50Hz AC 230V.  That is,  I want to convert the frequency of the signal at both ends.  At one end multiply it by double and at the other end devide by half. How can I do this?

I tried the cyclo converter circuit but couldn't find the proper result. Is there any modification required in the cyclo converter or any other method available?

Comment: If you are looking at a [cycloconverter,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloconverter) then you probably aren't looking at "signals."  That kind of thing is generally applied to power lines.

Comment: Normally a frequency doubler would work, but they are not meant for raw power, only signals. The parts would be bulky and expensive and waste power.

Answer (score 0):

I can give a suggestion. May not work out. It goes something like this, if you don't want to get into complicated complex solution such as AC(50)-DC-AC(100)-DC-AC(150). Please comment if solution seems to be in lines of what you have been implementing.

[image]

- A: 50 Hz signal
- After passing A signal through a switched converter working to produce something like in Fig. B(Switching at 90 degree to alternate the waveform), you get a 100Hz signal. Now this signal contains many harmonics as n*100Hz.
- To get the required 100Hz signal, you can pass it through the LPF Filter with cut-off frequency of 100Hz. Getting required 100 Hz signal.

**Note:** There are many things that needs to be pointed out in this simple looking solution such as:

- Desired Output 230V may not be the output as there would be attenuation in the circuit
- Proper 100Hz sine wave may not be there. Since LPF filter are not exactly cut-off at frequency. They have some roll-off rate.
- Converter might be required to go from A->B. Might complicate the solution
- Solution seems to be similar to cyclo-converter
- Filter used may be bulky if used for high-power.

Comment: Yes its exectly i want but with the usage of these switched converters as you said harmonics, it will be the problems. suggest if you have more ideas in this or any other. cause i want atleast 90% same output as input (50hz AC)